# Eloquent InnoDB cannot add foreign key (error 1215)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, innodb

I am trying to create a table with foreign keys with eloquent ORM and **InnoDB** engine and it is failing with error :

General error: **1215 Cannot add external index constraint**.

The thing is that it **works on mariaDB**, i tried on an other computer.

This is the table :

```
DB::schema()->create('client', function($table){
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id')
              ->comment('Identifiant du client');

        $table->string('cli_nom', 25)
              ->comment('Nom ou raison sociale du client');

        $table->string('cli_activite', 5)
              ->comment('Code NAF activité');

        $table->text('cli_activite_desc')
              ->comment('Description du code NAF');

        $table->integer('cli_adresse_id')
            ->unsigned()
            ->comment('Id de l adresse du client');

        $table->integer('cli_type')
            ->comment('1:client ou 0:prospect');

        $table->integer('cli_theme_couleur_id')
            ->unsigned()
            ->comment('Id de la couleur de personnalisation d interface');

        $table->integer('cli_theme_id')
            ->unsigned()
            ->comment('Id du theme acheté par le client');

        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('cli_adresse_id')
              ->references('id')->on('adresse')
              ->onDelete('restrict');

        $table->foreign('cli_theme_couleur_id')
            ->references('id')->on('theme_couleur')
            ->onDelete('restrict');

        $table->foreign('cli_theme_id')
            ->references('id')->on('theme')
            ->onDelete('restrict');
    });
```

I also tried to add index() to the fk:

```
            $table->integer('cli_adresse_id')
            ->unsigned()
            ->index()
            ->comment('Id de l adresse du client');
```

**EDIT**

This is the referenced table :

```
 DB::schema()->create('adresse', function($table){
        $table->increments('id')
            ->unsigned()
            ->comment('Identifiant de l adresse');

        $table->integer('adr_num')
              ->comment('Numéro de rue');

        $table->string('adr_voie', 250)
              ->comment('Rue ou voie dans la ville');

        $table->string('adr_cp', 10)
              ->comment('Code postal de l adresse');

        $table->string('adr_ville', 250)
              ->comment('Nom de la ville de l adresse');

        $table->integer('adr_pays')
              ->comment('Identifiant du pays');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: And the other table, the one you're referencing? Can you post migration for that one as well?

Comment: Run your migration, then after getting the error go to your favourite MySQL manager sw and run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` and check out the detailed reason why the foreign key creation has failed. You will most likely be able to sort out the issue yourself after that.

Comment: @Shadow after `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` i got : `Error in foreign key constraint of table app_indus/#sql-11d4_1d0d:
 foreign key (`cli_adresse_id`) references `adresse` (`id`) on delete restrict:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`id`) on delete restrict`

Comment: @Shadow thanks for the tip. The adresse table engine was MyISAM, that's why it was failing.